# How to throttle the speed of an event without using Rx Framework

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, system.reactive, c#-5.0

I want to throttle the speed of an event, How I can achieve this without using Microsoft Rx framework. I had done this with the help of Rx. But what I am trying is, I need to throttle Map's View changed event based on a time slot. Is it possible to implement the same without using Rx.

I am not allowed to use Rx and I have to keep the binary size as small as possible.

Comment: You should at least constrain the problem by explaining what's wrong with Rx and what properties the solution needs to have, otherwise the question is just too broad. My first reaction right now is this: If Rx works (and it does so elegantly) then why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The issue is due to some reasons, I can't include the Rx Library to my project. So only for achieving this, adding such a big library seems odd.

Comment: Any reason for down vote? I am asking for an alternative method. What is wrong with it?

Comment: If I was you I'd revisit the question of using a library that gives you what you need. It's < 1Mb. To hack out error free code in SO to reproduce the same functionality doesn't seem a productive use of time to me. At the very least, give it a go yourself and show some code if you get stuck.

Comment: I am trying for a solution to this for last two days.. Mean time I thought if someone had an idea that may help me. That's it. Anyway thank for your response.

Comment: Just use your own timer.  Enable it when you get the changed event.  Disable it when it ticks and do your stuff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works, if your event is of type `EventHandler<EventArgs>` for example. It creates a wrapper for your event handler that is throttled:

```
private EventHandler<EventArgs> CreateThrottledEventHandler(
    EventHandler<EventArgs> handler, 
    TimeSpan throttle)
{   
    bool throttling = false;
    return (s,e) =>
    {
        if(throttling) return;              
        handler(s,e);
        throttling = true;
        Task.Delay(throttle).ContinueWith(_ => throttling = false);
    };
}
```

Attach like this:

```
this.SomeEvent += CreateThrottledEventHandler(
    (s,e) => Console.WriteLine("I am throttled!"),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Although, you should store the handler returned from `CreateThrottledEventHandler` if you need to unwire it with `-=` later.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how i can attach this into an existing event.

Comment: Edited in example of attaching it.

Comment: Any reason for not adding Await for Task.Delay()

Comment: No. Just being nice to .NET 4.0 people.

Comment: So my doubt is, Is that work without await in windows 8? Seems like the Task.Delay work synchronously

Comment: Although I only tested on Window 8 desktop, Task.Delay is not synchronous on any platform AFAIK - at least not on the default task scheduler; something else must be going on in your case. Clearly for the above code to work properly, the resetting of the 'throttle' flag must be done asynchronously otherwise the event delegate chain is blocked.

Comment: Perfect! Glad you've shared this, elegant solution.

Comment: Very nice, but it seems to me that the `bool throttling` variable is not accessed in a thread-safe manner. I would use `Volatile.Read`/`Volatile.Write` on every access point to this variable. Maybe it's redundant, but I would prefer to err on the side of safety.

Answer (score 16):

I believe the following requirements are essential in a 'throttled' event handler:

- The **first** event is raised immediately.
- Subsequent events - which occur within the throttling period - are *ignored*.
- The **last** event to occur during the throttling period is *guaranteed* to be raised, once the throttling period has expired.

Considering those requirements, the previously-accepted answer was not satisfactory; it correctly fulfills the first two requirements, but it does not guarantee that the last event will eventually be raised.  I think that point is particularly important, because events which are raised with high frequency typically represent 'change of state' and/or 'user requests'; and we *always* want to receive the last update for changes in state or user interaction.

In an effort to satisfy all these requirements, I created my own generic "ThrottledEventHandler" class.

```
public class ThrottledEventHandler<TArgs>
    where TArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly EventHandler<TArgs> _innerHandler;
    private readonly EventHandler<TArgs> _outerHandler;
    private readonly Timer _throttleTimer;

    private readonly object _throttleLock = new object();
    private Action _delayedHandler = null;

    public ThrottledEventHandler(EventHandler<TArgs> handler, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        _innerHandler = handler;
        _outerHandler = HandleIncomingEvent;
        _throttleTimer = new Timer(delay.TotalMilliseconds);
        _throttleTimer.Elapsed += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void HandleIncomingEvent(object sender, TArgs args)
    {
        lock (_throttleLock)
        {
            if (_throttleTimer.Enabled)
            {
                _delayedHandler = () => SendEventToHandler(sender, args);
            }
            else
            {
                SendEventToHandler(sender, args);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SendEventToHandler(object sender, TArgs args)
    {
        if (_innerHandler != null)
        {
            _innerHandler(sender, args);
            _throttleTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        lock (_throttleLock)
        {
            _throttleTimer.Stop();
            if (_delayedHandler != null)
            {
                _delayedHandler();
                _delayedHandler = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator EventHandler<TArgs>(ThrottledEventHandler<TArgs> throttledHandler)
    {
        return throttledHandler._outerHandler;
    }
}
```

Usage looks something like this:

```
myObject.MyFrequentlyRaisedEvent += new ThrottledEventHandler(MyActualEventHandler, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
```

Comment: Seems overengineered to me, in my attempts one tick handler seemed sufficient. Guess it has to do with the throttledEventHandler; personal favor probably to use a helperclass not add a handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Throttle` method, inspired by James World's [`CreateThrottledEventHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21404072/11178549) method, that mimics the behavior of the Rx [`Throttle/Debounce`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) operator. It propagates only events that come after a `dueTime` period of inactivity. This means that in case the source events are raised in quick succession, with no time gaps larger than `dueTime` between them, no event is going to be propagated.

```
/// <summary>Ignores events that are followed by another event within
/// a specified relative time duration.</summary>
public static EventHandler<TEventArgs> Throttle<TEventArgs>(
    EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler,
    TimeSpan dueTime)
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
    return (s, e) =>
    {
        var newTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            _ => handler(s, e), null, dueTime, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        var previousTimer = Interlocked.Exchange(ref timer, newTimer);
        previousTimer?.Dispose();
    };
}
```

Usage example:

```
public event EventHandler<int> SomeEvent;

//...

this.SomeEvent += Throttle<int>((s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received: {e}");
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

Comment: Hi Theodor! Hope you don't mind me asking in this context... is there an Rx.NET operator for actual Debounce logic in Rx.NET (as per ["Debounce vs Throttle"](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing) definition)? Sadly, Rx.NET docs are a bit outdated and lacking (Rx.js docs are more superior [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce)). Rx.NET is definitely not one of my strong skills, so I thought I'd ask before diving into [its source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) - tks! 

Comment: Hi @noseratio! Yes, there is a [`Throttle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229400(v=vs.103)) operator available in Rx. The docs are outdated indeed!

Comment: Yeah but there's a subtle difference: Throttle is for reducing the event emission rate ("fire at most once every 100ms"), while Debounce is for making sure the event won't be emitted again until a certain amount of time passed ("fire only if 100ms have passed since it was fired last time). It looks like Rx .NET `Throttle` is actually doing debouncing, as per existing docs?

Comment: @noseratio according to the docs of `Throttle`, *ignores the values from an observable sequence which are followed by another value before due time with the specified source, dueTime and scheduler.* AFAIK this means that each received value is never emitted immediately. There is always a delay equal to `dueTime` between receiving and emitting a value, unless the currently buffered value is preempted, in which case it is just discarded. The `Throttle` method of my answer attempts to replicate this behavior. TBH I don't know how the `Debounce` works in other Rx implementations.

Comment: Just to clarify, let's say, I want to call a spellcheck web api *only* if user stopped typing and 1s passed since the last keystroke. That'd be debouncing. With throttling, the web api would be called once in every 1s anyway, as long as the user keeps typing. I suppose I'll need to experiment with  Rx .NET to see what its `Throttle` is actually doing :)

Comment: @noseratio AFAIK it's doing debouncing, which is the desirable functionality in your case. But verifying it experimentally will certainly not hurt. 

Comment: Verified it using an `IAsyncEnumerable` simulation: https://gist.github.com/noseratio/b5745064ba05d4bcadc861c1a73679f9. `Throttle` is indeed debouncing, and the closet thing to actual throttling I've found was `Sample`.

Comment: ...while RxJS has all of them: `audit`, `auditTime`, `debounce`, `debounceTime`, `sample`, `sampleTime`, `throttle`, `throttleTime`. Envy! 