# An Rx observable that would act as ReplaySubject but only for the 1st subscriber?

Tags: javascript, c#, rxjs, reactive-programming, system.reactive

What's an elegant way of composing an Rx observable which would resemble [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject), but only emit the accumulated sequence *once* and for the first subscriber only (when that subscriber is connected)? After the 1st subscription, it should act just as a regular [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject).

This for a .NET project, but I'd equally appreciate JavaScript/RxJS answers.

I did google for potential solutions, and I'm about to roll out my own, similar to [how I approached](https://gist.github.com/noseratio/79268e55fb441d92ec28cffb2bbe72b8) `DistinctSubject`, eventually.

Comment: What's the use-case here?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I have a case where I buffer some events, and multiple consumers can be racing for the first batch, as they start observing. So it's like ReplaySubject, but replaying only to the one which wins the race. That's probably the best way I could describe it. I think I could solve it with bare TPL, but I'm interested in Rx solution from the learning perspective as well.

Comment: I have asked something similar a few months ago: [How to make a lightweight `Replay` operator that can be subscribed only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494884/how-to-make-a-lightweight-replay-operator-that-can-be-subscribed-only-once)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, tks, makes me think, maybe this scenario isn't so exotic :) In my case, I also need to make sure other subscribers will be receiving the fresh new events, but not before the 1st subscribed has observed all of the initial buffer (and then no more buffering). I'll get to it, I have a TPL solution in place so I'm not in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified slightly the implementation found in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494884/how-to-make-a-lightweight-replay-operator-that-can-be-subscribed-only-once), and changed the name of the class from `ReplayOnceSubject` to `ReplayFirstSubscriberOnlySubject`:

```
public class ReplayFirstSubscriberOnlySubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private ISubject<T> _subject = new ReplaySubject<T>();

    public void OnNext(T value) { lock (_locker) _subject.OnNext(value); }
    public void OnError(Exception error) { lock (_locker) _subject.OnError(error); }
    public void OnCompleted() { lock (_locker) _subject.OnCompleted(); }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(observer));
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_subject is ReplaySubject<T> replaySubject)
            {
                var subject = new Subject<T>();
                var subscription = subject.Subscribe(observer);
                // Now replay the buffered notifications
                replaySubject.Subscribe(subject).Dispose();
                replaySubject.Dispose();
                _subject = subject;
                return subscription;
            }
            else
                return _subject.Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably not the most efficient solution, since two different `lock`s are acquired on every operation (the `_locker` and the [internal](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/1ff45fbb832cf722dee875a83886dca25a923be3/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/ReplaySubject.cs#L218) `_gate`), but it
shouldn't be very bad either.

Comment: It's good! The only thing is, the lock will block event producers (those calling `OnNext`), while the buffer is played back to the 1st subscribers. Then again, that's how [`ReplaySubject` behaves](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/1ff45fbb832cf722dee875a83886dca25a923be3/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/ReplaySubject.cs#L350) as well. Thanks!

Comment: @noseratio when I implemented the `ReplayOnceSubject` I started with a lock-less implementation (`Interlocked.CompareExchange`). But things weren't going smooth, I don't remember the reason, and so I finally settled for the trusty `lock`. 

Comment: BTW do you know using `lock { ... }` can lead to nasty reentrancy issues on STA threads (WinForms, WPF etc). I used to have a mental picture that `Monitor.Enter/Exit` are wrappers for Win32 Critical Sections, but it turns they aren't: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1383#issuecomment-927750884

Comment: @noseratio I was not aware about the specific STA nuances, but I am very aware that if I `Cancel` a `CancellationTokenSource` or `TrySetResult` a `TaskCompletionSource` inside a `lock` protected region, it's likely that all hell will break loose. 

Comment: @noseratio btw I implemented hastily the `IDisposable` interface, without checking what happens if the `Subscribe` is invoked on a disposed subject. You may want to take a look at it, if you are planning to put this class in production.

Comment: @noseratio I just remembered what was the problem with omitting the lock. Without locking there was no guarantee that the first subscriber will receive all the buffered notifications before receiving any future notification. Which was quite a big problem. 

Comment: Yep exactly, and we also don't want new subscribers to receive anything before that. So while playback is happening, the producer of new events is blocked. That might be not too exciting but that's how the original  `ReplaySubject` works too.

Comment: Hi @noseratio. To keep the answer simple, I removed the half-baked implementation of the `IDisposable` interface. Also I've uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/06d39354ab211d27ecdc65f91ec943b7) a `ReplayLimitedSubscriptionsSubject<T>` custom subject that discards the replay buffer after a specified number of subscriptions, instead of after the first subscription. It's not thoroughly tested. I wrote it with the intention to solve another problem, but the solution didn't go well for other reasons (probably).

Comment: Theo, a bit off topic, I wonder if with your Rx background you ever you stumbled upon a proper .NET implementation of what is [`throttle` in RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttle)? There's a bit of terminology confusion here, I believe .NET `Throttle` is what is [`debounce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce) in RxJS and other implementations, while actual throttle operator is missing in Rx .NET (the closest to it is probably `Sample`).

Comment: @noseratio I think we've discussed this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400514/how-to-throttle-the-speed-of-an-event-without-using-rx-framework/65553763#65553763). I haven't learned anything new about the throttle/debounce family of operators since then. :-)

Comment: OMG, I had a dejavu feeling but didn't even bother to search ‍♂️Thank you! Pretty sure I'll ask one more time when I actually need it, so I apologies in advance 

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Theodor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178549/theodor-zoulias) for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390202/470818)!

I've ported your logic to typescript. Since javascript and nodejs are single-threaded and there are no `async` operations, I did not need the lock mechanism that the .NET code needed.

---

### Code

```
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';

/**
 * A custom `ReplaySubject` that only replays the buffered events
 * to the first subscriber. All subsequent subscribers will only
 * receive new events, as if subscribed to a `Subject`.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390202/470818
 */
export class ReplayFirstSubscriberOnlySubject<T>
  implements rxjs.SubjectLike<T>
{
  /**
   * Buffers events and replays them to the first subscriber.
   * Continues to emit new events.
   */
  private replaySubject: rxjs.Subject<T>;

  /**
   * Subject used for all subsequent subscribers.
   * They only receive new emits, not buffered events before subscribing.
   */
  private subject?: rxjs.Subject<T>;

  constructor() {
    this.replaySubject = new rxjs.ReplaySubject<T>();
  }

  public next(value: T): void {
    // Notify the first subscriber of the value.
    this.replaySubject.next(value);
    // Notify all subsequent subscribers of the value.
    this.subject?.next(value);
  }

  public error(error: Error): void {
    // Notify the first subscriber of the error.
    this.replaySubject.error(error);
    // Notify all subsequent subscribers of the error.
    this.subject?.error(error);
  }

  public complete(): void {
    // Notify the first subscriber of the completion.
    this.replaySubject.complete();
    // Notify all subsequent subscribers of the completion.
    this.subject?.complete();
  }

  public subscribe(observer: Partial<rxjs.Observer<T>>): rxjs.Unsubscribable {
    const subscription = (this.subject ?? this.replaySubject).subscribe(
      observer
    );
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = new rxjs.Subject<T>();
    }
    return subscription;
  }
}
```

### Jest Test

```
describe('ReplayFirstSubscriberOnlySubject', () => {
  it('should replay buffered events to the first subscriber only', () => {
    const subscriber1NextSpy = jest.fn();
    const subscriber2NextSpy = jest.fn();

    const subscriber1CompleteSpy = jest.fn();
    const subscriber2CompleteSpy = jest.fn();

    const subject = new ReplayFirstSubscriberOnlySubject<string>();

    // buffer events for the first subscriber
    subject.next('A');
    subject.next('B');

    // first subscriber
    subject.subscribe({
      next: subscriber1NextSpy,
      complete: subscriber1CompleteSpy,
    });

    // new event to all current subscribers
    subject.next('C');

    // second subscriber
    subject.subscribe({
      next: subscriber2NextSpy,
      complete: subscriber2CompleteSpy,
    });

    // new event to all current subscribers
    subject.next('D');

    // done
    subject.complete();

    // First subscriber receives all buffered and new events.
    expect(subscriber1NextSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);
    expect(subscriber1NextSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'A');
    expect(subscriber1NextSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 'B');
    expect(subscriber1NextSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(3, 'C');
    expect(subscriber1NextSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(4, 'D');
    expect(subscriber1CompleteSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    // Subsequent subscribers only receive new events.
    expect(subscriber2NextSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(subscriber2NextSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'D');
    expect(subscriber2CompleteSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```